# LSTM accuracy decrease/drop problem while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I followed [this](https://github.com/lily-aung/Time-series-classification-using-a-modified-LSTM-approach-from-accelerometer-based-data/blob/master/code-modelbuilding-composite/Composite-Model.ipynb)

and this is the code of the model.

```
model = Sequential()

# Recurrent layer
model.add(LSTM(44, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, 
recurrent_dropout=0.1))

# Fully connected layer
model.add(Dense(44, activation='relu'))

# Recurrent layer
model.add(LSTM(44, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.1, 
recurrent_dropout=0.1))

# Fully connected layer
model.add(Dense(44, activation='relu'))

# Dropout for regularization
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the number of training sets, test sets = 6158, 2640

```
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_split = 0.33, epochs=500, batch_size=20, verbose=1)
```

and below graphs show the accuracy and loss of the LSTM model.

epoch 50

[image]
[image]

epoch 500

[image]
[image]

Q. At epoch 50, it fluctuates without convergence, so I change the epoch to 500. So now it converges, but the fluctuation problem is the same. Also, additional problem arose. **For training, the accuracy is high at first and then decreases. For validation, the accuracy is initially high, then decreases and then increases again**. What is the problem with the model? Looking at the loss graph, it doesn't seem to be an overfitting problem. maybe a dataset problem?

Comment: do you see the same issue with a different validation split?

Comment: @ekrall yes i changed the validation_split 0.33 to 0.1, but same thing happened.

Comment: Might try reducing the dropout next, to see if that is contributing

Comment: @ekrall Thanks. I changed the dropout 0.5 to 0.2 and also, remove the dropout layer, but still same. Would it be better to try using a different LSTM model to check the problem?

Comment: @ekrall When remove all of the dropout(LSTM dropout and doprout layer), the width of the section where the accuracy is high at first and then decreases has been reduced.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info